# ffmpeg 2.8.x cross compile error on mac os x 10.10

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, ffmpeg

I want to cross compile ffmpeg 2.8.x on Mac OS X 10.10, but I got the following error.

```
HOSTCC  libavcodec/cabac_tablegen.o
In file included from libavcodec/cabac_tablegen.c:25:
In file included from libavcodec/cabac_functions.h:43:
libavcodec/arm/cabac.h:96:25: error: value '24' out of range for constraint 'M'
          [byte]"M"(offsetof(CABACContext, bytestream)),
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: 
  expanded from macro 'offsetof'
#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [libavcodec/cabac_tablegen.o] Error 1
```

The error show some error in host cc, the host cc is `clang-700.1.81`

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Before I upgrade Xcode to 7.2, it worked fine.

For ffmpeg 3.x, there is no such problem. But the ffmpeg version I need is 2.8.x. How can I fix without downgrade Xcode to previous version?

Answer (score 1):

It was the problems of host cc.

I kept the current version Xcode and install another version command line tools `Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_6.4`.

The clang version for this command line tools is

```
$ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

And change the host cc to this compiler when configure ffmpeg.

```
./configure --host-cc=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
```

Now it can get compiled without error.